# run setx command using java

Tags: java, path, setx

I am writing a java code that will append a path string to the %PATH% variable using java

In command prompt the command is

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\my Path\"
```

In java here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class AddToPATHVariable {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        String folderPath = "C:\\my Path\\";
        System.out.println(folderPath);
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime() ;
        Process p = rt.exec("setx PATH \"%PATH%;" + folderPath + "\"");
        p.waitFor();
        p.destroy();
    }

}
```

The issue is that my command line prompt is append the new string perfectly. But java code is make the value to path variable to be %PATH%;C:\my Path\

someone please guide me in this regard.

Comment: are you talking about double backslash (\\ ) converting to Single backslash?

Comment: @NutterzUK I mean the the previous path value is replace my hardcoded string %PATH%

Comment: @Orion...no, I mean the the previous path value is replace my hardcoded string %PATH%

Answer (score 3):

Well, as nothing is in charge of converting `%PATH%` it simply is not converted !

More seriously, it is the `cmd.exe` interpretor that actually does the translation of environment variables and you do not use it. To have it to work, you must :

1. convert the environment variable `PATH` to its value in java code

   ```
   String path = System.getenv("PATH");
   ```
2. use the converted String in your command

   ```
   Process p = rt.exec("setx PATH \"" + path + ";" + folderPath + "\"");
   ```

EDIT :

To really be sure of what happens, you can display the generated command before executing it :

```
String cmd = "setx PATH \"" + path + ";" + folderPath + "\"";
Process p = rt.exec(cmd);
```

Comment: I do the same...and even have debugged it but in the end result, it appends some part from the start of the original path instead of the folderpath.

Comment: getenv is returning the PATH variable 3 times

Comment: @JaveriaHabib I updated my anwser to be sure of the executed command. But beware : setx modify the environment for **futures** windows command, not for current one. Look at `setx /?` it should say something like : *in an local system, variables created or changed by this tool will be used by future command windows, but not in current CMD.EXE window* (translation is mine, my system speaks french :-) )